# $24$th derivative of $x^3 \sin x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there an easy way to calculate $24$th derivative of $x^3 \sin x$?

Comment: you can use the Leibníz formula

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you elaborate the method with an answer?

Comment: Compute the derivatives of order 1, 2, 3, 4, guess the general formula, prove it with induction, and check your answer here: http://www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: $$\left(x^3\sin(x)\right)^{(24)} = \sum_{k=0}^{24}
\binom{24}{k}\left(x^3\right)^{(k)}\left(\sin(x)\right)^{(24-k)}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{3}
\binom{24}{k}\left(x^3\right)^{(k)}\left(\sin(x)\right)^{(24-k)}
$$

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek Differentiation with tabular integration ?

Comment: @A---B I have never facepalmed so hard. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a formula for the $n$-th derivative of a product of two functions, similar to $(a+b)^n$:

$$(f\cdot g)^{(n)} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}\cdot g^{(n-k)}$$

In your case, $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = \sin x$. Note that for $x^3$ only the first $3$ derivatives are non-zero, so we can simplify this to

$$(x^3 \sin x)^{(24)} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^3 \binom{n}{k}(x^3)^{(k)}(\sin x)^{(n-k)}$$

Finally, use the fact that the derivatives of $\sin x$ are periodic: $(\sin x)^{(4)} = \sin x$

$$(x^3 \sin x)^{(24)} = (x^3)^{(0)} (\sin x)^{(24)} + 24 (x^3)^{(1)} (\sin x)^{(23)} +\\ + 276 (x^3)^{(2)} (\sin x)^{(22)} + 2024(x^3)^{(3)} (\sin x)^{(21)} =\\
= x^3 \sin x - 72 x^2 \cos x - 1656 x \sin x + 12144 \cos x$$

Comment: @lisyarus - that's not the correct Leibniz formula. You left out all the binomial coefficients.

Comment: @achillehui Sure, thank you! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the 4th derivative of $x^3$ is $0$ now use leibnitz rule ie $\frac {d^n (fg)}{dx^n}=\sum_{i=0} ^n {n\choose i} f^{(i)}g^{(n-i)} $ where powers indicate the order of derivative of that function with respect to $x $ in your case $f (x)=x^3,g (x)=\sin (x) $